# Conda installation - pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have a jupyter environment I created based on [jupyter/pyspark-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook)

It has underneath an anaconda installation...

Since I have to install some python packages that exists only in pypi repo AND some packages directly from private git repo, I used pip (instead on conda install ...) to do it

```
pip2 install packageOnlyInPypi
pip3 install packageOnlyInPypi
pip2 install git+http://1.1.1.1./name/privateLib.git
pip3 install git+http://1.1.1.1./name/privateLib.git
```

When I create a Jupyter python notebook and run this command, I can see the packages listed:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

Also, running this I can see the packages.

```
conda list
```

[image]

**The problem is:**

```
import privateLib
```

**inside a iPython notebook gives me an import error.**

Already tried:

1. restart kernel
2. reinstall package

Comment: What error? an `ImportError`? Be more specific please.

Comment: yes. ImportError: No module named ...

Comment: When dealing with multiple installation never use just `pip2` or `pip3` command. It's better to use `path_to_python_executable -m pip install package_name`. This way you can make sure, that you have installed package properly.

Comment: I receive a message: "no module named pip" when I run "python2 -m pip install (...)"      Running with python3 works fine

Comment: actually path_to_python_executable advice is not recommended...

http://ebanshi.cc/questions/1868194/installing-pip-in-different-versions-of-python